# php - Won't redirect based on referrer parent URL inside iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I have a page with an iframe with the following code. Basically I want it to act like a portal. Depending on which page they're visiting this from, they will see a different thing. When I tried to get the referrer with echo, it managed to fetch the parent URL but wouldn't redirect properly. Instead it would go to the default. I was wondering if this is something that is impossible to do?

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

switch($referrer) {
   case "https://domain1.org":
      header("Location: https://example.org/one");
      break;
   case "http://domain2.org");
      header("Location: https://example.org/two");
      break;
   case "https://domain3.org":
      header("Location: https://example.org/three");
      break;
   default:
      header("Location: https://example.org");
}
```

**EDIT 1:** It would only redirect to the case header if I change it to the iframe URL, not the parent. Otherwise it would redirect to the default header.

<strike>**EDIT 2:** I've set up a testing environment here. The problem persists.</strike>

Comment: So you are not getting any errors (logs)? Not clear if the header is firing or not. What exactly is not working? If the redirect, then likely headers already sent type issue. Please elaborate a bit. I'm slow.

Comment: @ficuscr : Sorry if there wasn't sufficient information. No errors whatsoever. Logs are good. The header is firing but only the default header. Redirect doesn't detect the parent URL as referrer but echo does.

Comment: Does the referrer string exactly match the ones you are testing for? Perhaps the strings in your `case` statement are just parts of it.

Comment: What jeroen said, or, you need to detect referer on page A and pass that value as a GET variable (one, two, etc..) on the URL used to reach page B. Not clear if you are now checking for that on page B when it is too late. Nature of web development, pass it on URL or tuck it away in session.

Comment: side note: HTTP_REFERER is browser set, unreliable, and should be avoided if at all possible

Comment: @jeroen : Yes the strings exactly match. I've just tried the same code on another domain and it also didn't work there.

Comment: @ficuscr : I've tried with javascript to fetch the current document URL as GET variable and didn't work. I'm not sure if that's the method you had in mind?

Comment: @rtfm : I see. Noted. Thanks for the info. Any way around it then?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @SMH : Google Chrome

Comment: Can you please echo the $referrer before the switch and tell me the output?

Comment: @SMH : echo before switch shows parent URL

Comment: with all the https and backslashes?

Comment: @SMH : Yes it shows the complete URL

Comment: there is lack of information, we dont know which user agent, the user agent may not have set this on, sorry I can't help you unless you provide more information.

Comment: Ben, this is trivial, ignore most of the comments. This should and would work fine, you are making some dumb mistake. Would take this to chat if I remembered how.

Comment: @ficuscr : I most likely am but I don't know what it is. I'd love to take this to chat too but I don't have 20 rep.

Comment: @ficuscr : Just wanted to say that I've updated and made a testing environment so you can see it in real time if you're still interested in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a variable to the iframe URL so that it would detect the given variable rather than the parent URL. Not what I had in mind but works well as an alternative in my case.

```
<iframe src="https://example.org/redirect.php?variable=redirect1"></iframe>

$var = $_GET['variable'];

switch($var) {
   case "redirect1":
      header("Location: https://example.org/one");
      break;
   case "redirect2";
      header("Location: https://example.org/two");
      break;
   case "redirect3":
      header("Location: https://example.org/three");
      break;
   default:
      header("Location: https://example.org");
}
```